# Using enum parameters in myBatis dynamic SQL

Tags: string, enums, ibatis, dynamic-sql, mybatis

How to do dynamic SQL in myBatis 3.1.1 based on an enum constant parameter?

Comment: [After MyBatis 3.4.1](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/549), if your mapper method has only one param which is enum type and you don't annotate it with `@Param`, for example, that enum type is `Gender`, you can use `test="name == 'MALE'"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**How to do dynamic SQL based on enum constants**

```
public enum Test {
    A, B;
}

Mapper.java:
    int test(@Param("t") Test t);

Mapper.xml:
    <select id="test" resultType="int">
        select
        <choose>
            <when test='t.name().equals("A")'>65</when>
            <when test='t.name().equals("B")'>66</when>
            <otherwise>0</otherwise>
        </choose>
    </select>
```

**Notes**

- The test expression must refer to strings using double quotes, not single quotes.
- You can't compare constants, only strings.

Comment: This however throws NullPointerException in case t is null

Comment: @Jurass you can easily avoid null exception by inverting order of comparison ie: <when test='"A".equals(t.name())'>65</when>

Answer (score 10):

MyBatis allows `==` instead of `equals` for strings in `if` (or `when`) statements. So the following would also work (quotes don't matter):

```
public enum Test {
    A, B;
}
```

Mapper.java:

```
int test(@Param("t") Test t);
```

Mapper.xml:

```
<select id="test" resultType="int">
    select
    <choose>
        <when test="t.name() == 'A'">65</when>
        <when test="t.name() == 'B'">66</when>
        <otherwise>0</otherwise>
    </choose>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

Besides Tomer's answer, which works just fine, you can also compare enum values by using the [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/) notation.

(Comparing enum values directly has compile-time advantages, ie, if you change the enum members, the query will fail fast.)

If the Test enum lives in full.package.name as a public class, Test.java, then, in mapper.xml, you'd have:

```
<when test='t == @full.package.name.Test@A'>
```

If the Test enum is inside another class, like this:

```
package full.package.name;

public class ExampleClass {
    public enum Test {
        A, B
    }
}
```

Then, in mapper.xml you'd have:

```
<when test='t == @full.package.name.ExampleClass$Test@A'>
```

The $ sign is undocumented in the OGNL specification, I've found it 
[in the MyBatis issues page](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/810)

PS: Older versions of MyBatis (for instance, 3.2.3) show ugly errors if the OGNL string is not correct (like, NullPointerException). Newer versions show a more understandable error.

Answer (score -1):

```
public enum Test {
    A, B;
}

Mapper.java:
    int test(@Param("t") Test t);

Mapper.xml:
    <select id="test" resultType="int">
        select
        <choose>
            **<when test='t.name() == &quot;A&quot;'>65</when>
            <when test='t.name() == &quot;A&quot;'>66</when>**
            <otherwise>0</otherwise>
        </choose>
    </select>   

is another solution.
```